matplotlib dimension mismatch
I want to plot a numpy 2D array in 3D.
This is the code I have
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

NUM_ROWS = 360
NUM_COLS = 800 
RETURNS_PER_POINT = 3

fig = plt.figure()
ha = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

x = range(NUM_ROWS)
y = range(NUM_COLS)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y, indexing='ij')

first_return_area = np.random.rand(360, 800)
print(first_return_area.shape)
print(X.shape)

ha.plot(X, Y, first_return_area)
plt.show()

I got error
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes [original->remapped]: (288000,)  and requested shape (360,)

I don't understand because the printed lines shows they are exactly the same shape?
Would really appreciate if anyone could take a look, thanks in advance!

The error you are encountering occurs because the shapes of the arrays X, Y, and first_return_area do not align properly for the plotting function. In 3D plotting with plot in Matplotlib, each array needs to have the same shape to map the x, y, and z coordinates correctly.
However, in this case, you should use plot_surface for plotting a 3D surface where X, Y, and Z represent the coordinates of the points on the surface. Let's adjust the code accordingly:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

NUM_ROWS = 360
NUM_COLS = 800
RETURNS_PER_POINT = 3

fig = plt.figure()
ha = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

x = np.arange(NUM_ROWS)
y = np.arange(NUM_COLS)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y, indexing='ij')

first_return_area = np.random.rand(NUM_ROWS, NUM_COLS)

ha.plot_surface(X, Y, first_return_area, cmap='viridis')
plt.show()

This should resolve the broadcasting issue and allow you to plot the 3D surface correctly.

Thank you, this worked!
How to understand "each array needs to have the same shape to map the x, y, and z coordinates correctly" ?
Don't they need to have the same shape so that it becomes a sequence of (x, y, z) ?

Since you have x, y and z coordinates, we need to use the plot_surface function. In the question you were using the plot function which is used typically for 2d plotting. The error says that you are using a 2d plot function but giving x, y and x points.
Here are the relevant documentations:


plot_surface


plot


